# Spider not found, key issue

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have already made a working project using Scrapy but, it was kind of a mess, so i decided to do a more polished new one.

This question has been answered several times but none of the solutions are really helping me. The error is so basic I'm getting kind of frustrated.

When i try to run my spider, with 'scrapy crawl generic_spider' I get the error

```
KeyError: 'Spider not found: generic_spider'
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 170, in crawl
crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 198, in create_crawler
return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 202, in _create_crawler
spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
```

KeyError: 'Spider not found: generic_spider'

Also, my generic_spider and settings.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from genericScraper.items import GenericScraperItem
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

class GenericScraperSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "generic_spider"
    #Things

    def start_requests(self)

        #More things

    def parse_item(self, response)
```

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for genericScraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'genericScraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['genericScraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'genericScraper.spiders'
```

EDIT:

Tree (i dont know why only pycache is appearing, EDIT2: it seems tree only shows folders)

C:.

```
└───genericScraper
├───spiders
│   └───__pycache__
└───__pycache__
```

cfg

[settings]
default = genericScraper.settings

[deploy]
project = genericScraper

Comment: Are you sure your terminal working directory is in spider root directory? Also could you post your project tree? I think on Windows you can just type `tree` in terminal. Also contents of `scrapy.cfg`?

Comment: For creating the project, i used
scrapy startproject genericScraper
then i just added a new file in spiders with the name generic_spider
This is weird, because my other project is almost the same and it works just fine.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you encounter this issue you must ensure 3 things:

1. You are in root project directory (where `scrapy.cfg` is)
2. You have correct project structure with `scrapy.cfg` and spider in `project/spiders/spider.py`
3. Your spiders are valid classes that have `name` attribute

Terminal rundown:

```
$ pwd
/home/user/projects/scrapyexample
$ tree
.
├── scrapy.cfg
└── scrapyexample
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── middlewares.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        └── stackoverflow.py

$ cat scrapy.cfg 
[settings]
default = scrapyexample.settings

[deploy]
project = scrapyexample

$ cat scrapyexample/spiders/stackoverflow.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class StackoverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    #   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverlfow.om']
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverlfow.om/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: I dont know how but, i erased everything and created the project again following the rules and it worked!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The Spider File might not be at the exact location. it should be in spider folder.

Comment: Spider file is inside spiders folder. Can't find what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

Remove

> LOG_STDOUT = True

Having `LOG_STDOUT = True` in `settings.py` makes scrapyd for some reason to not see the spider, so removing the line from settings solved the problem!